Bochs not showing any output on screen
this is my first question here
I am new to the operating system world, I am trying to run this basic bootloder
after one hour of troubleshooting I am in a situation that my simulator is opening, but the screen is black
for context - I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 x64 and Bochs 2.7
the steps I took to fix the problems I had so far
1 - it could not use sdl - I changed it to sdl2
2 - it could not find some of the BIOS-bochs-latest and the VGABIOS-lgpl-latest
to fix I compiled bochs on my own and installed those files from GitHub in this link as instructed here
3- then I he'd a problem right after I open the simulator - I used this fix and essentially changed the bios address from 0xf0000 to 0xe0000
now I am in the situation that it all seams to work right, the simulator is opening, no crash. but also nothing - added an image
added image
I am expecting the system to load up ad show that it is booting from the floppy like the tutorial

Anything interesting in OSDev.log?

After you rebuilt BOCHs did you recreate (delete or move the existing file somewhere else) the BOCHS config (ie bochsrc.txt)?

Nothing interesting int the OSDev.log

Res after the build I moved all the files to the BOCHs folder including the floppy disk and the bochsrc.txt so I won’t have to specify the exact location in the config file, all the files that are mentioned in the bochsrc.txt including the bios and the vga file was moved to the BOCHs folder
